# /AF reference to file embedded into a PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am struggling to include into the PDF Catalog an "/AF" reference to an Embedded File object just added by the iTextSharp library. The following code works, but the string literal **PdfLiteral("[2 0 R]")** is unbearable, because the reference to an embedded file may of course have any other number than "2 0":

```
            PdfReader   reader = new PdfReader("C:\\ZUGFeRD\\zugferd_2p1_EN16931_Einfach_stripped.pdf");
        FileStream  outputstream = new FileStream("C:\\ZUGFeRD\\zugferd_2p1_EN16931_Einfach2.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        PdfStamper  stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, outputstream);
        PdfWriter   writer = stamp.Writer;

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\ZUGFeRD\\factur-x.xml");

        // Sample spec: Desc(factur-x.xml) / EF <</ UF 4 0 R / F 4 0 R >>/ Type / Filespec / AFRelationship / Alternative / F(factur-x.xml) / UF(factur - x.xml)
        PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "", "factur-x.xml", bytes, false, "text/xml", null);
        fs.Put(PdfName.AFRELATIONSHIP, new PdfName("Source"));
        
        stamp.AddFileAttachment("factur-x.xml", fs);

        stamp.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.AF, new PdfLiteral("[2 0 R]"));
        stamp.Close();
```

How can I write it better?

Comment: My /AFRelationship is fine: "Source", but the /AF reference is required in the PDF "Catalog", and it refers to the object "file specification" which in turn refers to the file stream object. I guess the problem is with the PdfStamper: it does not disclose the next "obj key" it is going to use, and I need it for a cross reference.

Comment: Exactly! It can potentially be [XYZ 0 R], but in my case it's always [2 0 R]. It works, but it's ugly :) Thanks for the reference to e-TaxInvoice-PDFgen, I'll try.